# Problema com User-Managed Transaction e Flush usando JTA e Arquillian

Tags: java, hibernate, jta

Eu estou fazendo alguns testes com JUnit e, pra injetar dependências no mesmo com CDI, adotei o Arquillian. Mas, há um problema que não descobri como resolver sem usar o método `flush()` do `EntityManager`.

Basicamente, eu preciso remover um objeto e verificar que ele não está na listagem de objetos, o que faço com os seguintes comandos:

`class1DAO.remove(1);`
`assertFalse(class1DAO.getAll().contains(object1FromClass1));`

O que o método: `remove(Class1 class1);`
do DAO faz é dar um: `entityManager.remove(class1);`
O que seria suficiente pra excluir o objeto. Pelo que eu entendi de Hibernate.

Já o método `getAll()` retorna um `entityManager.createQuery("from Class1 c", Class1.class).getResultList();`

Até aí, tudo bem! Mas o objeto excluído uma linha acima, no teste, vem na listagem do método `getAll()` e meu teste falha. A única forma que encontrei de evitar isso é dar um `entityManager.flush();` logo abaixo de `entityManager.remove(class1);`

Mas eu já estava utilizando Gerenciador de Transações e Controle de Injeção de Dependência, justamente, pra evitar precisar fazer isso na mão. Existe alguma forma de resolver isso, sem utilizar explicitamente o `flush()`?

Comment: posta ai seu teste !!

Comment: `Class1 class1 = class1DAO.add(new Class1("payment"));`
`assertTrue(classe1DAO.getAll().contains(class1));`

`class1DAO.remove(1);`
`assertFalse(class1DAO.getAll().contains(class1));`

Comment: O teste é, basicamente, esse. Adiciona, verifica, remove e verifica. Mas se eu não der um `flush()` no remove, o teste falha.

Comment: Removi minha resposta porque fiz confusão com o que você está perguntando. Sem o entityManager.flush() para remover dá problema, pois as alterações no banco de dados só são escritas após a confirmação da transação, o flush faz com que as alterações sejam escritas de forma imediata. Então quando você tenta acessar uma lista, a leitura dá o erro pois a transação ainda não foi confirmada.

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim:

```
@Test
public void delete()  {


    class1DAO.remove(1);//deleta


    assertNull( class1DAO.find(Class1.class, 1) );// se null ok.

}//
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso e retornou `null`, sim. Mas, como falei, ao utilizar o `getAll();` com uma query básica, ele não retorna `null` e, em um teste mais extenso, eu preciso que esses caras sejam removidos e não venham com o `getAll();`

Comment: Não entendi posta suas classe assim não d apara te ajuda muito.

Comment: Eu preciso, não só verificar que esse cara foi excluído. Se fosse isso, o `find` do EntityManager resolveria.

O problema é que mais na frente eu preciso trazer dados do banco e esse objeto não pode estar entre eles.

Comment: ai quando vc trazer todos do banco os dados deletados já não vão está mais entre eles.

Comment: Mas traz. Se eu der um `find(Class1.class, 1);` ele não vem, dá null. Mas se, depois eu der um `entityManager.createQuery("from Class1 c", Class1.class).getResultList();` ele vem junto.

Comment: entityManager.createQuery("from Class1 c", Class1.class).getResultList() aqui eele está buscando todos. Ideal é vc buscar o seu objeto padrão.

Comment: Mas eu preciso buscar todos.

Comment: por que vc precisa buscar todos

Comment: Preciso iterar sobre eles. Sabe como é possível dar flush através do UserTransaction?

Comment: Não entendi a frase.

Comment: Não estou tentando , entendendo pq vc está usando flush.

Comment: Porque sem flush, o remove não funciona.
Eu quero saber se é possível usar o UserTransaction ou um EntityManager do teste pra dar um flush no DAO. Tem como fazer isso? Sem ser com o EntityManager do DAO. Não quero mexer no DAO, mas, sim, dar o flush pelo teste.

Comment: posta suas classes sem elas fica difícil..